# Why can't i use doGet method in my servlet code?

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlets and i have developed a html page which has a submit button that triggers 
my servlet.Everything is working fine .But now i want to use GET method as my html page is not posting anything.Hence  i made the following changes:
1)In my page.html file, i replaced method="POST" with method="GET".
2)I changed doPost with doGet in my servlet.
But i'm getting error message that "GET not allowed here".Why is it so?
Here are the original files which work correctly(prior to making changes):

My page.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A simple revision of servlets</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="Idiot">
    <input type="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Deployment Descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<servlet>
<servlet-name>TangoCharlie</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Revise</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TangoCharlie</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Idiot</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And finally my servlet file named Revise.java

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Revise extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body><h3>Hello India</h3></body></html>");
    out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

Comment: it should work , just republish :)

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand, but are you implying that POST also doesn't work? If so, try placing your servlet class in a normal package. Packageless classes are namely by default invisible and unconstructable, although some containers+JVM combinations can do it. Always put publicly reuseable classes in a package anyway.

Comment: By the way, our [servlets wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) might give you a better introduction to servlets than what you're reading right now.

Comment: Hey BalusC ,by"as my html page is not posting anything",i mean that my html page doesn't send any form data to server.That's why i think that i should use GET.

Comment: There's indeed no form data at all in your HTML page. As first step, give your button a name and add some input fields.

Comment: I don't want to add any input fields.My aim is just to run the servlet without a single button on html page that too called using "POST" method .Now plz tell me,is it possible or not and why? (It works perfectly with POST as i mentioned already)

Comment: It look like that you didn't read the aforelinked servlets wiki page at all. The answer was in there! I posted a concrete answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I don't want to add any input fields.My aim is just to run the servlet without a single button on html page that too called using "POST" method.*

Just do the job in `doGet()` method (don't forget to properly rebuild/redeploy/restart the project after editing servlet code, otherwise you will still face a "HTTP 405: method not allowed" error) and invoke the URL of the servlet directly instead of the URL of the JSP in the browser's address bar.

So, the URL in browser address bar should be

> http://example.com/contextname/Idiot

instead of

> http://example.com/contextname/page.html

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, emitting HTML in a servlet is bad design. It should be done by a JSP. You can use `RequestDispatcher#forward()` to forward the request to a JSP after finishing the `doGet()` business logic. Further, packageless classes are also a bad design. You should always put publicly reuseable Java classes in a package. Packageless servlets will only work on certain combinations of Tomcat + JVM versions.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains concrete (and properly designed) Hello World examples